# .Net - Adding MODI into the Visual Studio

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2012, ocr, modi

. Net via ORC for `SharePoint` Designer in `Visual Studio 2012` installed, but the reference section in any reference the `Microsoft Office Document` imaginer did not come such as.

What should I do?

Comment: http://mehmetkurtipek.blogspot.in/2012/09/ocr-with-microsoft-office-document.html

Comment: http://mehmetkurtipek.blogspot.in/2012/09/ocr-with-microsoft-office-document.html

I used this site but do not get a result